# i need help finding the output error voltage due to Ibias and offset current

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: the question]

[image: the error due to Ib]
I have tried to do this question many times but cant get this question done can someone please help

[image: the error due to Ios]

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint to get started.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo2NtG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use the definitions of Iib and Ios to know the current flowing into (or out of) the inputs of OA1. Then calculate the voltage at the point shown, apply KCL (the current through R2 and R1 will be known) and the result should be easy.

It looks to me like you're trying to apply formulas without really understanding them, which is not a good approach. For example, you're ignoring R2  which is actually a major cause of the error.